# How do I limit the level of nesting on a recursive type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I have an `IMenu` interface that has a recursive key on the sub menu items as represented below.

```ts
interface IMenuItem {
  name: string;
  path: string;
  subMenu?: IMenuItem[]
}
```

How do I limit the level of nesting when someone creates an object of this type, to a static value, say 2 levels, over which TypeScript should throw an error.

```ts
// 1. Expecting this to work
const menu:IMenuItem[] = [
  { name: 'Dashboard', path: '/' },
  { name: 'Reports', path: '/reports' },
  { 
    name: 'Accounts',
    path: '/',
    subMenu: [
      { name: 'All', path: '/accounts' },
      { name: 'Create', path: '/accounts/create' },
    ],
  },
  { name: 'Settings', path: '/settings' },
];


// 2. How to make this throw an error
const menuAlt:IMenuItem[] = [
  { name: 'Dashboard', path: '/' },
  { name: 'Reports', path: '/reports' },
  { 
    name: 'Accounts',
    path: '/',
    subMenu: [
      { name: 'All', path: '/accounts' },
      {
        name: 'Create',
        path: '/accounts/create',
        // This level show not be accepted
        subMenu: [
          { name: 'admin', path: '/accounts/create-admin' },
          {
            name: 'client',
            path: '/accounts/create-admin',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  { name: 'Settings', path: '/settings' },
];
```

NOTE: I tried using the `Record` util but the types get out of hand for higher items support.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way using a lot more Typescript magic:

```js
type Length<T extends unknown[]> = 
  T extends { length: infer L } ? L : never;
type BuildTuple<L extends number, T extends unknown[] = []> = 
  T extends { length: L } ? T : BuildTuple<L, [...T, unknown]>;
type MinusOne<N extends number> = 
  BuildTuple<N> extends [...(infer U), unknown]
    ? Length<U>
    : never;

type BaseMenuItem = {
  name: string;
  path: string;
};

type MenuItem<Depth extends number> = Depth extends 0
  ? BaseMenuItem
  : BaseMenuItem & { subMenu?: MenuItem<MinusOne<Depth>>[] };

const x: MenuItem<4> = {
   [...] // Nesting up to 4 times
}
```

We first define a `MinusOne` utility function that takes a literal integer type and subtracts one to it (this requires building a tuple, removing one element from it, and then computing the length of the remaining tuple).
And then we recurse by removing one at each level until we reach 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to limit it to two, I guess the simplest is to make several types:

```js
interface IMenuItem {
  name: string;
  path: string;
  subMenu?: ISubMenuItem[]
}

interface ISubMenuItem {
  name: string;
  path: string;
}
```

<strike>Otherwise I don't know of any easy way to limit recursion to an arbitrary level.</strike>

Edit: See my other answer for a version parametric in the depth.

Comment: This is great. But I would wish for the levels of nesting to be customizable. Such that  if say I have a requirement of 3 levels support, I don't have to do a lot of repetition.